# Mongoose remove and create in get route

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a small issue with mongoose, what I am doing is getting data from online rss feeds, parsing it, and passing it to an array, from which I feed a mongoose model, and all this happens in the get route, what I want to accomplish is delete all the data first from the mongoose model and then populate it with the new data, but it always either deletes the data all together, since the parser iterates a few times, or it doesn't delete anything and the data just keeps adding to the model.

Here's my code

```
'use strict';
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const request = require('request');
const FeedParser = require('feedparser');
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const xray = require('x-ray')();
var Post = require('../models/post');
var dataArray = [];

router.get('/', function (req, res) {

    const fetch = (url) => {

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            if (!url) {
                return reject(new Error(`Bad URL (url: ${url}`));
            }

            const feedparser = new FeedParser();
            const items = [];

            feedparser.on('error', (e) => {
                return reject(e);
            }).on('readable', () => {
                // This is where the action is!
                var item;
                console.time('loading')
                while (item = feedparser.read()) {
                    items.push(item);
                }
            }).on('end', () => {
                resolve({
                    meta: feedparser.meta,
                    records: items
                });
            });

            request({
                method: 'GET',
                url: url
            }, (e, res, body) => {
                if (e) {
                    return reject(e);
                } else if (res.statusCode != 200) {
                    return reject(new Error(`Bad status code (status: ${res.statusCode}, url: ${url})`));
                }
                feedparser.end(body);
                feedparser.on('end', function () {
                    console.log('Done');
                });
            });
        });
    };

    Promise.map([
            'url',
            'url',                              
            'url',
            'url'], (url) => fetch(url), { concurrency: 4 }) // note that concurrency limit
        .then((feeds) => {
            feeds.forEach(feed => {
                feed.records.forEach(record => {
                    dataArray.push(record);
                });
            });
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });

    Post.remove({}, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log('collection removed');
        }
    });

    dataArray.forEach(post => {
        Post.create({
            title: post.title,
            content: post.description,
            created: post.date,
            image: post['rss:image']['#'],
            link: post.link
        }, function (err, newPost) {
            console.log(newPost.title);
        });
    });
    Post.find({}, function (err, posts) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.render('index/home', {
                posts: posts
            });
        }
    });
});


module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1):

None of this is going to run synchronously. You can do Something like this :

```
'use strict';
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const request = require('request');
const FeedParser = require('feedparser');
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const xray = require('x-ray')();
var Post = require('../models/post');
var dataArray = [];
const fetch;

router.get('/', function (req, res) {

Post.remove({}, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log('collection removed. Starting to fetch Posts from Service');
        fetch = (url) => {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                if (!url) {
                    return reject(new Error(`Bad URL (url: ${url}`));
                }

                const feedparser = new FeedParser();
                const items = [];

                feedparser.on('error', (e) => {
                    return reject(e);
                }).on('readable', () => {
                    // This is where the action is!
                    var item;
                    console.time('loading')
                    while (item = feedparser.read()) {
                        items.push(item);
                    }
                }).on('end', () => {
                    resolve({
                        meta: feedparser.meta,
                        records: items
                    });
                });

                request({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: url
                }, (e, res, body) => {
                    if (e) {
                        return reject(e);
                    } else if (res.statusCode != 200) {
                        return reject(new Error(`Bad status code (status: ${res.statusCode}, url: ${url})`));
                    }
                    feedparser.end(body);
                    feedparser.on('end', function () {
                        console.log('Done');
                    });
                });
            });
        };
    }
});

Promise.map([
        'url',
        'url',                              
        'url',
        'url'], (url) => fetch(url), { concurrency: 4 }) // note that concurrency limit
    .then((feeds) => {
        feeds.forEach(feed => {
            dataArray = dataArray.concat(feed.records);
            /*feed.records.forEach(record => {
                dataArray.push(record);
            });*/
        });
        console.log('inserting posts in the collection');
        dataArray.forEach(post => {
            Post.create({
                title: post.title,
                content: post.description,
                created: post.date,
                image: post['rss:image']['#'],
                link: post.link
            }, function (err, newPost) {
                console.log(newPost.title);
            });
        });

        console.log("Fetching posts from the collection");
        Post.find({}, function (err, posts) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                res.render('index/home', {
                    posts: posts
                });
            }
        });

    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
});


module.exports = router;
```

I haven't tested this. Please test it on your end. Let me know if there's an error or something.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the event thing? I tried your solution but it still does the same thing that I talked about originally, it just keeps adding to the collection each time I refresh. What I am trying to accomplish is just remove all the data and then add it again after the Promise.map, all that should happen once I refresh the page.

Comment: Do you need to first remove the items from the `Post` collection, then hit the service and get the posts data, and then add the data to to `Post` collection? Coz right now we are first fetching the data from the service, then removing all the posts from the `Post` Collection and then adding the posts again to it.

Comment: Yes, I want to remove all the items from the collection before anything happens, then add them to the collection again through the service.

Comment: What I mean is I don't want anything to be duplicated in the collection, I just want to remove all the old data and add the new data, and I want all this to happen when I refresh the page.

Comment: fetch is out of scope, the Promise.map function can't reach it. How do I go about this? should I put the Promise.map inside the initial promise funciton?

Comment: Update, I tried putting it in the initial promise function but that didn't work either.

Comment: Declared `const fetch` globally. Check if it works now. Any specific reason for using `fetch` as a `const`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108706/discussion-between-siddharth-ajmera-and-voldamere).